# How can i compare three strings using only one pointer and nothing else

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I want to have a program in C that reads 3 numbers and prints the bigger one, using only one pointer and no more variables. 
Can someone provide me with the code? I was not able to make it happen.
The only way i thought is to use a pointer like this: *p[3] but i do know if this is what we are asked to do.
I also thought of using malloc but i am not sure how

The prototype that we were given was:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)

{

 int*p;
 ...

 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but "provide me with the code" is not an on-topic question. Please show a [reasonable attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex), post your code showing where you got stuck and someone will be happy to help you debug the problem.

Comment: i thought of using a pointer like this *p[3] but is this what i am asked to do ?

Comment: I don't know what you're supposed to do because I did not create this assignment and I'm unaware of what is fair game within its seemingly arbitrarily-chosen constraints. You should ask your instructor if you need clarification on what you were asked to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to have a program in C that reads 3 numbers and prints the bigger one, using only one pointer and no more variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof *p); // assume it worked
    if (scanf("%d", p) != 1) /* error */; // read 1st number
    printf("%d\n", *p); // print 1st number
    if (scanf("%d", p) != 1) /* error */; // read 2nd number
    printf("%d\n", *p); // print 2nd number
    if (scanf("%d", p) != 1) /* error */; // read 3rd number
    printf("%d\n", *p); // print 3rd number
    free(p);
}
```

The program above, does what is required. In addition it prints the middle and smaller numbers!

---

Update using array of 3 pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *p[3];
    p[0] = malloc(sizeof *p[0]); // assume it worked
    p[1] = malloc(sizeof *p[0]); // assume it worked
    p[2] = malloc(sizeof *p[0]); // assume it worked
    if (scanf("%d", p[0]) != 1) /* error */; // read 1st number
    if (scanf("%d", p[1]) != 1) /* error */; // read 2nd number
    if (scanf("%d", p[2]) != 1) /* error */; // read 3rd number
    if ((*p[0] >= *p[1]) && (*p[0] >= *p[2])) printf("%d\n", *p[0]);
    if ((*p[1] > *p[0]) && (*p[1] >= *p[2])) printf("%d\n", *p[1]);
    if ((*p[2] > *p[0]) && (*p[2] > *p[1])) printf("%d\n", *p[2]);
    free(p[2]);
    free(p[1]);
    free(p[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. In line 6(int *p;)  i get this message. [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: and the point of the exercise is to compare the numbers so it can print the bigger one. if you can help with that too, i would appreciate it

Comment: "[Error] invalid conversion from 'void' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]": add `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error bad compiler` / `#endif` before the includes.

Comment: With **one** single variable its impossible to compare **two** values.

Comment: That makes it possible, but it is not a pointer: it's an array if pointers. See update.